# Why compareTo() has its own implemented body while Comparable is an interface?

Tags: java, generics, comparable, compareto

I know that there is one method in Interface `Comparable<T>`, that is `compareTo()`. I assume that it's just  a function name without any implementation in it and when any class implements Comparable interface, that class have to override that method. But then I read the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

and find out that Comparable also return a value, int, and has its own implementation without the need of overriding it in the implementing class.

Eg, this example:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T a, T b) {
    if (a == null) {
        if (b == null) return a;
        else return b;
    }
    if (b == null)
        return a;
    return **a.compareTo(b)** > 0 ? a : b;
}
```

Comment: That's because you're working with a `Comparable` object reference, not with the `compareTo` method only (as probably you think you're doing).

Comment: "can be functioned as a normal methods"? Can you rephrase this sentence towards making more sense? I don't understand what you are asking, honestly.

Comment: The Docs just state what `compareTo` is supposed to return (its *contract*). Why do you think it implies that it has an actual implementation in the interface?

Comment: yah, because in my example, it said: return a.compareTo(b) > 0 ? a:b; and it works so I suppose that compareTo has something in it. :(

Comment: @AmazingQuestion In your example your actually using the implementation of class T, which is a class that implements Comparable and that got an implementation of the compareTo method.

Comment: I mean I used to believe that methods in an interface are methods without implementation in their body. But then this example makes me think that compareTo() in Comparable interface has its own implementation and the implementing class,which is max, dont have to override compareTo(). and that make me confuse

Comment: The method requires that the arguments are instances of a class T that implements Comparable. Precisly because implementing an interface means that one must give implementations of the interface methods is it possible to call compareTo on this objects.

Comment: You can do `Collections.sort(list)` on a list of objects implementing a natural order with compareTo. And you can sort (differently) with `Collections.sort(list, myComparable)` - useful when the object is not Comparable itself, or you want a different order (article by lowest price first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparable is an interface meaning that objects that implement it must implement its method. You are right in that it only has one method to implement compareTo(T o). You are also right about the method returning an integer. compareTo returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

The reason an interface like this exists is to make java more generic. Since the interface defines a standard name and basis for comparing, this standard can then be used in other methods such as Collections.sort or Collections.binarySearch. This way if you want to sort 500 objects you just created in a Vector, all you have to do is implement compareTo(T o), and then you could call Collections.sort(myVector).

I think you are getting confused with the fact that some objects already implement the interface Comparable such as Integer, String, UUID, or CharBuffer. These ones will work 'out of the box', but if you try to pass a Vector of JPanels (a class that does not implement Comparable) to Collections.sort, you will get an error.

Answer (score 4):

There's no such "implementation" in the method you provided - that method is just a *caller* of `compareTo`. The type `T extends Comparable<T>` means some variable type `T` that implements `Comparable<T>`.

For example, `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`, so you could call:

```
Integer i = max(123, 42);
```

`String` implements `Comparable<String>`, so you could also call:

```
String s = max("asdf", "blah");
```

That's the power of a generic method - that its body can be reused on various types. In this case, the method has an *upper bound* of `Comparable<T>` on its type variable `T`, in order to guarantee that it can call `compareTo` on instances of `T`.

For example, this won't compile because `Object` doesn't implement `Comparable<Object>`:

```
// Object is the common supertype of Integer and String
Object o = max(42, "asdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have it's own implementation. It just declares an operation like interfaces do. In your example you are calling the operation `compareTo()` on `a` which is of type `Comparable`. This is possible because `Comparable` declares that operation.

But `Comparable` is only the so called static type of that variable. At runtime it has a dynamic type. This means that it points to an object that is a subtype of `Comparable` (implements it) and therefore also has to implement `compareTo`. The object `a` points to can't be directly of type `Comparable` since you can't create objects of interface types.

It seems to me that you should read up on object orientation, subtyping and polymorphism. Explaining it in detail would be to exessive for this site.